# Why isn't the ENTIRE JPanel repainting?

Tags: java, swing, graphics, jpanel, paintcomponent

Why is it in Java that when I try to move my window from the side of the screen to the center, then entire JPanel doesn't repaint it self?

Example: This is what happened when I tried to drag the window from the side of the screen (so only about half of the window was visible) to the center:

[image: CrazyHorse]

If I add a component listener and then put `repaint()` in the `componentMoved` method, it will work fine, but then it will repaint every time the window is moved.

Relevant code:

```
import java.awt.BorderLayout;
import java.awt.Color;
import java.awt.Graphics;
import java.awt.Graphics2D;
import java.awt.event.ComponentEvent;
import java.awt.event.ComponentListener;

import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JPanel;

public class TEST extends JFrame
{

    public TEST()
    {
        super ("TEST!");
        setSize (500,400);
        setLocationRelativeTo(null);
        setContentPane(new MyPanel());
        addComponentListener(this);
    }

    class MyPanel extends JPanel
    {   
        public void paintComponent (Graphics g)
        {

            super.paintComponent(g);

            Graphics g2d =  (Graphics2D) g;

            int R = (int)(Math.random()*256);
            int G = (int)(Math.random()*256);
            int B= (int)(Math.random()*256);
            Color color = new Color(R, G, B);

            g2d.setColor(color);
            g2d.fillOval(0, 0, getWidth(), getHeight());

        }
    }

    public static void main (String[] args)
    {
        TEST t = new TEST();
        t.setVisible(true);
    }
}
```

Comment: You seem to have a thread race condition, where the panel is been full painted, but the updates are been...overridden some how, with new random colors.  Ensure that you UI is created and started within the context of the Event Dispatching Thread, see [Initial Threads](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/concurrency/initial.html) for more details.  Also, what OS are you using?

Comment: just a side note: Graphics g2d =  (Graphics2D) g;
  that case does nothing (as you cast Graphics -> Graphics2D -> Graphics)

Comment: @Joeblade But, unless you case it, you can't use all the nice goodies in `Graphics2D`...which the OP isn't using...

Comment: @MadProgrammer yeah I was just pointing out that after his cast, he was implicitly casting it back to Graphics (as the variable g2d is actually a Graphics, not a Graphics2D)

Comment: @VinceEmigh That would explain the banding, as pointed out by camickr in his answer, this seems to be an optimisation issue in the painting process...

Comment: @MadProgrammer
 - using the `invokeLater` code, there was no difference
 - this is running on Windows 8

@Joeblade
 - woops, I completely missed that, I did in fact mean `Graphics2D`, thanks

Comment: @whoareyou It's still safer then what you were doing, I think camickr hit on the problem/solution

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Interesting, I've never noticed this before.

When you drag the frame outside the bounds of the desktop nothing happens. However, when you drag the frame back towards the center the component is repainted but with a clipped painting area. Depending on how fast you move the frame the clip width (assuming horizontal dragging) could be a couple of pixels or many pixels wide.

You can verify this by adding the following in your paintComponent() method:

```
 System.out.println(g.getClipBounds());
```

This obviously is controlled by the Swing painting mechanism and is not something we can control.

The solution is to NOT change the painting color every time the paintComponent() method is called, because as you have noticed you can't control when paintComponent() is called. So make the color of the oval a property of your class and generate the random color when the class is created.

Comment: I see, when I move it slowly, the width changes from 484 to about 1 or 2. I was just experimenting in Java because I know this also happens in C#. I'd also like to add that, when moving the frame from outside the desktop bounds either horizontally or vertically, this effect is reproduced. However, if you drag is diagonally, then it will repaint it as it should. Weird ...

Comment: @whoareyou, it makes sense that diagonal dragging works. The clip region is just a rectangle of the area that need to be painted. When you drag horizontally the width is only a couple of pixels, but the height is the entire height. When you drag vertically the width is the entire width and the height is a couple of pixels. When you drag diagonally you combine the maximum width/height of the horizontal and vertical dragging which means you need to repaint the entire width and height. Don't forget to "accept" the answer if it answers your question.